# Complex SQL query. one aggregate function inside another

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
CREATE TABLE Director
(
     [Id] INT,
     [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX),
     PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Movie
(
     [Id] INT,
     [Title] NVARCHAR(MAX), 
     [DurationMinutes] INT, 
     [ReleaseDate] DATETIME,
     [DirectorId] INT,
     [Rating] INT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (Id),
     FOREIGN KEY (DirectorId) REFERENCES Director(Id)
);

--ActorId reference actor which participated in certain movie
CREATE TABLE MovieActor
(
     [MovieId] INT,
     [ActorId] INT,
     FOREIGN KEY (MovieId) REFERENCES Movie(Id)
);
```

I have that table setup, from which I need to locate: Names of directors, who directed 2 or more movies with length >= 60 minutes in which of each movies(!) 3 to 7 actors participated. Rating of the film must be 9 or higher, and release date must be before 2006.

I've come up with this solution:

```sql
SELECT Name
FROM Director d
JOIN Movie m ON d.Id = m.DirectorId
JOIN MovieActor ma ON m.Id = ma.MovieId
WHERE ReleaseDate <= '2005-12-31'
  AND Rating >= 9
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ma.ActorId) BETWEEN 3 AND 7 
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN m.DurationMinutes >= 60 THEN m.DurationMinutes END) >= 2;
```

But it filter through ALL actors in ALL suitable movies - it returns how many distinct actors participated in director works, instead of only full-length films.

```sql
SELECT Name
FROM Director d
JOIN Movie m ON d.Id = m.DirectorId
JOIN MovieActor ma ON m.Id = ma.MovieId
WHERE ReleaseDate <= '2005-12-31'
  AND Rating >= 9
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN m.DurationMinutes >= 60 
AND COUNT(DISTINCT ma.ActorId) BETWEEN 3 AND 7 > THEN m.Id END) >= 2;
```

But this code throws an error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

---

**Edited:** Added testcases and wanted output.

Let's use these cases:

```sql
INSERT INTO Director
    ([Id], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 'Bebopvsky'),
    (2, 'Tarrantino'),
    (3, 'CubeRick')
;

INSERT INTO Movie
    ([Id], [Title], [DurationMinutes], [ReleaseDate], [DirectorId], [Rating])
VALUES
    (1, 'Platform for soul', 121, '2002-12-31', 2, 9),
    (2, 'Full-featured access management', 62, '2002-01-01', 3, 10),
    (3, 'Robust LDAP server for Java', 73, '2005-05-25', 3, 9),
    (4, 'Man of Rain', 114, '2004-07-21', 1, 10),
    (5, 'Man of Arms', 152, '2003-02-17', 1, 9),
    (6, 'Man of War', 93, '2003-07-05', 2, 9),
    (7, 'Man of Legs', 23, '2004-11-11', 2, 9),
    (8, 'Mof', 75, '2002-11-11', 2, 10)
;

INSERT INTO MovieActor
    ([MovieId], [ActorId])
VALUES
    (1,1), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5),    
    (2,1), (2,5),
    (3,1), (3,2), (3,4),
    (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4), 
    (5,1), (5,2), (5,3), (5,4), (5,5),
    (6,1), (6,2), 
    (7,2), (7,4), (7,5),
    (8,1), (8,4)
;
```

For our purpuses lets make all movie Date and Rating valid.

Director #1.
Have two films - *#4* and *#5*, both of them full-length and have 4 and 5 actors respectively. So he will be in output.

Director #2.
Have four films - *#1, #6, #7, #8*. *#1, #6, #8* are full-length and only *#1, #7* have 4 and 3 actors. So he dosn't have simultaneously two films with proper cast and length, so he won't be in output.

Director #3
Have two films - *#2, #3*. Both of them are full-length, but *#2* have only 2 actors. So he won't be in output.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us understand this a little better. DDL and attempts are great, but knowing your goal really help us with the final piece by of the puzzle.

Comment: I don't think you can use aggregate function in the same case statement. the first one does not have case statement and the error one has two count function being used HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN m.DurationMinutes >= 60 
AND COUNT(DISTINCT ma.ActorId) BETWEEN 3 AND 7 > THEN m.Id END) >= 2 You need to separate it but sample data and expected result would really help.

Comment: @Avi Updated post with cases and output.

Comment: @Larnu Updated post with cases and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want two levels of aggregation, one at the movie level and the other at the director level:

```
SELECT Name
FROM (SELECT M.ID, D.Name, COUNT(*) as NumActors
      FROM Director d JOIN
           Movie m
           ON d.ID = m.DirectorID JOIN
           MovieActor ma
           ON m.ID = ma.MovieID
      WHERE m.ReleaseDate < '2006-01-01' AND
            m.Rating >= 9 AND
            m.DurationMinutes >= 60
      GROUP BY D.Name, M.ID
      HAVING COUNT(*) BETWEEN 3 AND 7
     ) m 
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: The release date was before 2016, not after.

Comment: ok... It's a minor issue, but enough to return nothing based on your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, the filters are explained in the query:

```
select d.Name
from Director d
  join Movie m
    on m.DirectorId=d.Id
   and m.DurationMinutes>=60 -- length >= 60 minutes
   and m.Rating>=9 -- Rating of the film must be 9 or higher
   and year(m.ReleaseDate)<2006 -- release date must be before 2006
  cross apply (
    select 1 as Pass
    from MovieActor ma
    where ma.MovieId=m.Id
    group by ma.MovieId
    having count(1) between 3 and 7 -- 3 to 7 actors participated
  ) a
group by d.Name
having count(1)>=2 -- directed 2 or more movies
```